# Where is the argument for this JavaScript callback function being defined?

Tags: javascript, callback

I've been confused about callback functions for some time and I found a simple code snippet that illustrates my confusion.  This is from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp):

```
var str = "Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car";
var res = str.replace(/blue|house|car/gi, function (x) {
    return x.toUpperCase();
});
```

This is a representative example of my confusion with callbacks. I don't understand how `x` in the argument `function(x)` is being populated.  I'm looking at the [documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) and I see that matches are being passed to `x`, but I don't understand the underlying principle.  Is there a rule like " the argument of a callback function is populated by the previous argument," or is this behavior specific to String.replace()?  How can I extrapolate and apply this to all callback functions that I find?

Comment: The JavaScript code sets the arguments... It is like you writing a method with arguments `function foo (x,y,z) {}` and calling it. `foo(1,2,3);`. In this case you are writing the function, and they are calling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `replace` function is called and passed two arguments.

The `replace` function (which is provided by the underlying JS engine, so its source code does not show up in your question) does *stuff*.

Among the stuff it does is call the function you pass as the second argument (`newSubstr`). When `replace` calls `newSubstr`, `replace` passes `newSubstr` an argument.

> Is there a rule like " the argument of a callback function is populated by the previous argument,"

No. It is populated through whatever way the code calling the callback is designed to do.

> this behavior specific to String.replace()?

Yes

> How can I extrapolate and apply this to all callback functions that I find?

You can't.

Read their manuals or source code instead.